# Mezuzah on attic door

Tags: mezuzah

Assuming an attic large enough to require a mezuzah (see [Yoreh Deah 286:13](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%92)), is it necessary to put a mezuzah on a horizontal [attic door](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attic_ladder)? Does it qualify as a lintel? Should the thickness of the ceiling be considered a doorpost? Shall a blessing be recited?

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/225406/jewish/Which-Rooms-Require-a-Mezuzah.htm - "An attic also requires a mezuzah unless it is entered via a "trapdoor" (a horizontal opening in the floor rather than a vertical opening in a wall)." - Doesn't bring a source though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 11:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.11.20?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=he), citing [Noda Biyehudah Tinyana 184](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=1447#p=205&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=), says no: only a standing door requires a mezuzah.